# Is it possible choose from contacts when entering email address into a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to recreate the gmail to: type field but for entering in data to a spreadsheet.  So if a person starts typing in an email address it will look at their contacts (and domain contacts) and show a filtered set of emails.

Comment: throw a search box in the sidebar

Comment: As Zig said, you can't because no event is detected. if your list is not too long, data validation showing a dropdown list could be a (less sexy ;) alternative.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant because there is no event to detect the user typing.
What you can do is add a menu item that looks at the active cell and attempt to do the autocomplete on the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using Data Validation.

1. Get a CSV of the contacts.
2. Import those contacts into a sheet on the spreadsheet
3. use a formula similar to (= A1 & " " & B1) to create a filed that you want to search on. In my case I combined First Name and Last Name
4. Open a new sheet and right -click cell A1.  Use data validation to pull from the column you created in the previous sheet.
5. just start typing in the box and it opens up like the to: field in an email box.

I did this with 400 names and saw no performance issue.

Comment: All this can be done using script methods, no need to manually import csv an use the sheet to get the values. That said, when I suggested it for "not too long" lists it was not because of performance issues but simple ease of use... could be tedious to scroll long lists.

Comment: Nice.  The nice thing about long lists is that they filter down as you type.  I just did this with 450 student names.